# Python and memory usage when opening files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

When opening and appending to a file in python, does that file get loaded into memory? I'm asking this because I'm writing a program where I write to several files in a round-robin fashion where I have the guarantee that any one file can fit into memory but not all files can fit into memory at the same time. Opening and closing files every time I append is not an option since that would be too slow. As such, I would need all the files opened simultaneously.

Comment: That depends on what exactly you do. Just `open(...)` won’t read anything into memory, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO. Regarding the documentations of `open()` wraps a system call and returns a file object (Not the content of file): https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> Open a file, returning an object of the file type described in section
> File Objects.

The file contents are not loaded into RAM unless you read the file with eg.: `readlines()`, `read()`